# Язык стандартных виджетов PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, qt-designer

Использую *PyQt5* и *Qt Designer* для разработки своего приложения.

В процессе его работы иногда необходим вызов `QMessageBox` и `QDialog`. 
Кнопки в этих виджетах имеют стандартный текст на английском языке, например, "**`Yes`**" и "**`No`**", "**`Save`**" и "**`Discard`**".

Несмотря на то, что в *Qt Designer* свойству `locale` присвоено значение `Russian`.

Как это исправить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вам надо переопределить стандартные кнопки, которые используются. Например так:

**ok_cancel.ui**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>510</width>
    <height>323</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <widget class="QDialogButtonBox" name="buttonBox">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>150</x>
      <y>80</y>
      <width>156</width>
      <height>23</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="accessibleName">
     <string comment="Дааа"/>
    </property>
    <property name="inputMethodHints">
     <set>Qt::ImhNone</set>
    </property>
    <property name="standardButtons">
     <set>QDialogButtonBox::Cancel|QDialogButtonBox::Ok</set>
    </property>
    <property name="centerButtons">
     <bool>false</bool>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**main.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(510, 323)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.buttonBox = QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.buttonBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 80, 156, 23))
        self.buttonBox.setAccessibleName("")
        self.buttonBox.setInputMethodHints(QtCore.Qt.ImhNone)
        self.buttonBox.setStandardButtons(QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Cancel|QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Ok)
        self.buttonBox.setCenterButtons(False)
        self.buttonBox.setObjectName("buttonBox")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.buttonBox.clear()
        buttonAceptar  = self.buttonBox.addButton("Да хочу", QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.YesRole)    
        buttonCancelar = self.buttonBox.addButton("Отменить", QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.RejectRole) 

        self.buttonBox.clicked.connect(self.buttonBoxClicked)
        
    def buttonBoxClicked(self, btn):
        print(f'{btn.text()}')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]